# Open video with opencv, string too long error?

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to open an avi file using openCV:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const string path = "C:\\Users\\name\\file.avi";
    VideoCapture captRefrnc(path);
    if (!captRefrnc.isOpened())
    {
        cout << "Could not open reference " << endl;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

However, the output is the following:

```
[ERROR:0] global C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap.cpp (166) cv::VideoCapture::open VIDEOIO(CV_IMAGES): raised OpenCV exception:

OpenCV(4.5.4) C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_images.cpp:235: error: (-5:Bad argument) CAP_IMAGES: error, expected '0?[1-9][du]' pattern, got: h¾∟#± in function 'cv::icvExtractPattern'


[ERROR:0] global C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap.cpp (175) cv::VideoCapture::open VIDEOIO(CV_MJPEG): raised C++ exception:

string too long

Could not open reference
```

I do not understand what this means though? Can openCV just not handle .avi files?

Comment: `cout << cv::getBuildInformation()` and add the `Video I/O` section to your question

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Does not seem to work. For what it's worth I just downloaded the windows release from sourceforge. I also just found out the error does not occur when I execute a release version, only when I execute the debug version in Visual Studio.

Comment: that's not enough info to work with. explain everything you can possibly think of about "the debug version" that you have.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz The only thing I can think of is that when buidling the debug version it uses opencv_world454d.dll, while in the release version it uses opencv_world454.dll. I do also use visual studio 2017, while the folder is called vc15, but I'm not sure if this would matter.

Comment: `vc15` is `VS 2017` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#History -- so you just let slip out that you built opencv yourself. that means you also ran cmake yourself. you should share the complete *configure* (not build, configure) step of cmake, or at least the section titled `Video I/O`. use cmake-gui for comfort.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz no I did not build it myself, this directory is what you get when you download precomplied openVC from sourceforge.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz but maybe I can rebuild from source and maybe it’ll work then

Comment: potentially. you really need to provide the Video I/O section of `getBuildInformation()`. "does not seem to work" is no error description at all. I'm guessing that the _real_ code you run doesn't use *exactly* `"C:\\Users\\name\\file.avi"`, right?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz no that’s not the actual file name, but the file name is not the problem I think, since it does work when I build the release. I will try to compile tomorrow and hopefully then it’ll work.

Comment: yes, for a debug build of your program, you'll need to *link* to the debug libraries (and only those), and make sure the debug dlls are in the path. I'm not even sure the versioned binary releases of OpenCV contain debug libraries and dlls. maybe, maybe not. linking to both debug and release builds of the libraries does cause trouble every time someone accidentally does it.